# Android Kotlin Do not concatenate test displayed with setText. Use resource string with placeholders

Tags: android, string, kotlin, settext

And also "String literal in setText cannot be translated "

Now there are posts on this, but nothing seems working for me. Or need a proper explanation.
How to use string resources
Getting warning on this

```
 pTxt.text = "Total : $ $price"
```

Here, price is a value

if use this

```
pTxt.setText(R.string.displayPriceMsg, price)
```

it gives an error.

tried String.format() but giving garbage value.

Have this in strings.xml

```
<string name="displayPriceMsg">Total : $ %1$d</string>
```

Comment: If something gives an error, then please include that error in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass format arguments to the `getString` method:

```kotlin
pTxt.text = context.getString(R.string.displayPriceMsg, price)
```

Comment: I didn't got about context to which you have in solution.

Comment: you need instance of `Context` or `Resources` class to get string from resources. For example, you can use your activity as context. If you set text for `pTxt` in the activity class you can just write `pTxt.text = getString(R.string.displayPriceMsg, price)`

Comment: Can I have multiple string resource ids in it?

Comment: unfortunately, no